# Pandas 12 month Rolling average

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a 12 month rolling average and having a hard time with it.

This is the example data and the code.

```
data = {
    'Att' : ['red','red','red','red','tan','tan','tan','tan','cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan','cyan','red','red','red','red','tan','tan','tan','tan','cyan','cyan','red'],
    'loc' : ['A','A',      'B','B',    'A','A',    'B','B','A','A', 'B','B','A','A', 'B','B','A','A', 'B','B','A','A', 'B','B'],
    'Date' : ['3/14/2022 10:05','3/14/2022 10:05','4/20/2022 12:18','5/4/2022 7:42','6/1/2022 12:45','3/1/2022 11:46','8/2/2022 10:30','8/2/2022 10:30','9/22/2022 13:08','10/20/2022 13:46','11/8/2022 9:00','12/12/2022 9:58','1/19/2022 9:43','5/25/2022 8:57','6/22/2022 9:18','7/20/2022 13:13','8/25/2022 8:35','9/22/2022 9:35','4/5/2022 10:42','10/20/2022 10:32','11/16/2022 8:43','12/21/2022 8:36','1/14/2022 9:30','2/18/2022 11:26'],
    'Result' : [28,19,23,31,40,63,71,41,55,59,28,40,3.9,12,15,13,18,15,36,16,15,26,13,16],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df.sort_values([ 'loc','Date',], inplace=True)
df.to_clipboard(index=False)
df
# %%
for ana in list(df['Att'].unique()):
    dfa = df[df['Att']==ana]
    dfa.sort_values(['Date', 'loc'], inplace=True)
    # I tried another option of pivot_table here but this removes some values that are in the same month. 
    dfa = dfa.pivot(values='Result',index='Date',columns='loc' ).reset_index()

    dfa.set_index(keys='Date', inplace=True)
    dfa = dfa.rolling(12,min_periods=1).mean()
    dfa['Att'] = ana
    print(dfa)
```

Below is another option I tried this removes some values that are in the same month. If I change the `aggfunc='mean'` this creates a calculation error of averaging averages.

```
    dfa['Date'] = dfa['Date'].dt.to_period('M').dt.to_timestamp('M')
    dfa = dfa.pivot_table(values='Result',index='Date',columns='loc', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
```

I would like to do something like `'12M'` (see below) but this creates an error.

```
dfa = dfa.rolling('12M',min_periods=1).mean()
```

Answer (score 1):

Rolling by month would though an error because it is not a fixed period. The closest would be rolling by `365D`. Also, `for ana in list(df['Att'].unique()):` always scream for `groupby`:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])    
df = df.set_index('Date').sort_index()

df['rolling_mean'] = df.groupby('Att', sort=False)['Result'].transform(lambda x: x.rolling('365D').mean())
```

Output:

```
                      Att loc  Result  rolling_mean
Date                                               
2022-01-14 09:30:00  cyan   B    13.0     13.000000
2022-01-19 09:43:00  cyan   A     3.9      8.450000
2022-02-18 11:26:00   red   B    16.0     16.000000
2022-03-01 11:46:00   tan   A    63.0     63.000000
2022-03-14 10:05:00   red   A    28.0     22.000000
2022-03-14 10:05:00   red   A    19.0     21.000000
2022-04-05 10:42:00   tan   B    36.0     49.500000
2022-04-20 12:18:00   red   B    23.0     21.500000
2022-05-04 07:42:00   red   B    31.0     23.400000
2022-05-25 08:57:00   red   A    12.0     21.500000
2022-06-01 12:45:00   tan   A    40.0     46.333333
2022-06-22 09:18:00   red   B    15.0     20.571429
2022-07-20 13:13:00   red   B    13.0     19.625000
2022-08-02 10:30:00   tan   B    41.0     45.000000
2022-08-02 10:30:00   tan   B    71.0     50.200000
2022-08-25 08:35:00   red   A    18.0     19.444444
2022-09-22 09:35:00   tan   A    15.0     44.333333
2022-09-22 13:08:00  cyan   A    55.0     23.966667
2022-10-20 10:32:00   tan   B    16.0     40.285714
2022-10-20 13:46:00  cyan   A    59.0     32.725000
2022-11-08 09:00:00  cyan   B    28.0     31.780000
2022-11-16 08:43:00   tan   A    15.0     37.125000
2022-12-12 09:58:00  cyan   B    40.0     33.150000
2022-12-21 08:36:00  cyan   A    26.0     32.128571
```

Comment: How would you pivot this data so you end up with the "A" and "B" as the columns and the end of months as the index rolling_mean as the values? When have done it I get an error saying that  there is duplicate entries.

Comment: You need to aggregate by monthly before rolling: `groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='M', key='Date'), 'loc'])['Result'].mean/sum()`, then you can `unstack` the `loc` without problem.

Comment: I am not fulling understanding this part ` .mean/sum() `. The problem is I can not average numbers that have already been averaged. So I can not take a mean in the groupby then take another mean in the rolling.

Comment: groupby Month to have sum/count of the Result, then you can roll by the months and calculate the weighted average of the sum, where the weights are the counts. That's your rolling average.